# Only one option is prechecked instead of several

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net, checkboxlist

I am working on a project that pulls in data from several SQL tables. When I click on a row to edit, the whole checkboxlist is populated but the problem is that I need the checkboxes pertaining to that row to be prechecked. So when I add a row, I check several checkboxes but when I edit the new row I just added, only one checkbox is prechecked. I have checked on the SQL table and all the options are there. 
Here is my ASP.NET code:

```
    <div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 80px;">
        <div>
            <h3>Available Entities</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 500px;">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbAvailableEntities" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; display: block; margin-right: 150px;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveProject" runat="server" Text="Save Project" OnClick="btnSaveProject_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="btnClose_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
        private void PopulateProjectEntities()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].Corporation WHERE IsEntity <> 0 ORDER BY CompanyName";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        ListItem _listProjectEntities = new ListItem();
                        _listProjectEntities.Text = sdr["CompanyName"].ToString();
                        _listProjectEntities.Value = sdr["CorpId"].ToString();
                        cbAvailableEntities.Items.Add(_listProjectEntities);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }


    public void GetSelectedEntities()
    {

        //create the connection and command objects
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        //populate the command object
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT a.CorpID, a.CompanyName FROM [dbo].[Corporation] a Left join [dbo].[ProjectCovEntity] b on a.CorpID = b.CorpID WHERE b.ProjectID = " + _pID;

        using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    cbAvailableEntities.Items.FindByValue(sdr["CorpID"].ToString()).Selected = true;
                    ListItem _listPE = new ListItem();
                    _listPE.Text = sdr["CompanyName"].ToString();
                    _listPE.Value = sdr["CorpID"].ToString();
                    cbAvailableEntities.Items.Add(_listPE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have been stuck on this for several weeks now and I have done a lot of research for this. I have even looked up youtube videos for this. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I don't see you setting the checkbox checked anywhere.  cbAvailableEntities.Items.FindByValue(sdr["CorpID"].ToString()).Selected = true; only selects the item. Should this check the cb? If so, it should be Checked = true.

Comment: @Sami - Yes, that should be checked, however, when I put 
cbAvailableEntities.Items.FindByValue(sdr["CorpID"].ToString()).Checked = true;
I get an error. Not sure if I should type out the whole line differently to set it to checked instead of selected.

Comment: That's because the item is a listitem. You need to cast it to checkbox. Don't have a compiler here but I'll check it a bit later and post an example.

Comment: I tried changing it from ListItem to CheckBox and from ListItem to CheckBoxList. Still had no luck but I may be doing it wrong. I would really appreciate it if you showed me when you get a chance.

Comment: As soon as I get to my pc. Hour or two and I'll try.

Comment: Actually the correct property to set is `Selected`. I think I'm missing something here. On your `GetSelectedEntities()` method you're looking for the item before you create it? Is this an editing method? If that's on purpose, you need to post more of your code. I can't find out where the problem is.

Comment: When I use that method, I want the whole list to show and with some of the options preselected. This code is for a web page that will update a row in the SQL table.

Comment: But does the `cbAvailableEntities` already have items when you call that method? If so, are you creating the items a second time on the method. If not, you need to set the `Selected` value after creating the item.

Comment: @Sami how do I do that?

Comment: @Sami Problem is that I need the whole list there and at the same time, I need the options selected pertaining to the row that is chosen for editing.

Comment: Are you editing the item on the same `CheckBoxList` that you're using for the complete list? Are your reading the database for the same values that already are on the list to see which items should be checked?

Comment: @Sami I am editing what is checked. Not the CheckBoxList. For example, there are 5 options. I have options 2 and 3 checked for the 1st row of the SQL Table. I want to edit that row and have options 2-4 checked. What's happening right now, is that when I go to edit the row, only option 2 is checked. Not 2 and 3 like it is on the table. Like I said, only one option is checked when I go to edit a row and I need all options that were checked to appear checked.

Comment: That's exactly why I can't follow the logic on your code. Maybe some key part is missing. On `cbAvailableEntities.Items.FindByValue(sdr["CorpID"].ToString()).Selected = true;` you set an existing checkbox selected. Then after that you create a new one and add it to the checkboxlist. So that's why I'm asking, do you want to set existing items checked or create new ones.

Comment: @Sami I apologize for the confusion. I want to set existing items to be checked per the row I choose to edit. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try commenting out the last 4 rows od the while loop in GetSelectedEntities(). Also have you tried running the query on an sql client to see what it returns? Are you sure you get more than 1 row? If the query returns several rows, you should see duplicate checkboxes.

Comment: @Sami I just tried out the query on the SQL client and it works and I get several. Now when I run the program, it crashes on that line in the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (sdr.Read()) 
{
    ListItem currentCheckBox = cbAvailableEntities.Items.FindByValue(sdr["CorpID"].ToString());
    if (currentCheckBox != null) 
    {
        currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Found this answer on another post.